# Ruby graphql resolver alternative: method hooking --- how does it work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql, graphql-ruby

I need to add custom fields to graphql response, so I considered implementing my own custom resolver. However seeing [this](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/blob/master/guides/fields/resolvers.md), I asked myself if I really need a custom resolver:

> First, ask yourself ...
> Do you really need a Resolver? Putting logic in a Resolver has some downsides:
>
> - Since it's coupled to GraphQL, it's harder to test than a plain ol' Ruby object in your app
> - Since the base class comes from GraphQL-Ruby, it's subject to upstream changes which may require updates in your code

Well, I couldn't agree more. But I don't understand how the following alternative approach works.

> Here are a few alternatives to consider:
>
> - Put display logic (sorting, filtering, etc.) into a plain ol' Ruby class in your app, and test that class
> - Hook up that object with a method, for example:
>
> ```rb
> field :recommended_items, [Types::Item], null: false
> def recommended_items
>   ItemRecommendation.new(user: context[:viewer]).items
> end
> ```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem obvious to me.

I have a `Request` model that has `has_many` relationship with `Messages`.

```rb
def Request
   has_many :messages, -> { order(created_at: :desc, id: :desc) }

   def unread_message_count(user)
    return messages.unread(user).count
  end
end
```

I want to add `unread_message_count` field to graphql `RequestType` but I'm lost at:

```rb
class RequestType < Types::BaseObject
  field :unread_message_count, Integer, null: false

  def unread_message_count
    user = context[:current_user]
    // here
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it was easy, you can refer to the actual model in graphql type using `Types::BaseObject#object` method.

So in this case, it was:

```rb
class RequestType < Types::BaseObject
  field :unread_message_count, Integer, null: false

  def unread_message_count
    user = context[:current_user]
    user.nil? ? 0 : object.unread_message_count(user)
  end
end
```